# How to install non-homebrew dependencies (resources) so that they can be used for building the formula?

Tags: macos, homebrew

My formula depends on a number of libraries which I pre-compiled and distribute as `tar.gz` archives with headers and binaries. Now, I need these archives to be unpacked and referred to during `configure` process for my package. How can I achieve that?

I tried defining `resource` like that:

```
resource "openfec" do
  url "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8000/openfec-1.4.2-macos.tar.gz"
  sha256 "3c419365e4a778b3537b8dd3d1d31238045e06fff008438eccb1cfd4fdb10812"
end
```

and then staging it like this in my formula's `def install` methhod:

```
  resource("openfec").stage { lib.install "bin/Release/libopenfec.a" }
  resource("openfec").stage { include.install "src" }
```

But I don't understand where does it install it and how can I get a full path to these folders (namely `lib` and `include`) so that I can pass them as environmental variable to my the `configure` script of my formula when I do `system "configure" ...` call.

Relevant question here -- will `bin.install` and `include.install` accept folders as arguments?